# Formatting the vertical spacing in a list and placement of the date

Tags: formatting, lists

This  a follow up question.

When I change the font of my document, the positioning of the date changes a few mm left or right --  how to amend the code so that this does not happen-- I think a `\dimexpr` to calculate textwidth or linewidth but not sure how-- the date needs to stay aligned with rhead

Secondly I need to reduce the vertical spacing in the paras numbered (a) to (h)

Though I went through the enumerate documentation and tried the commands at page 2 
• Vertical spacing:
– topsep
– partopsep
– parsep
– itemsep
but these have no effect on the vertical spacing
Kindly advise

```latex
    \documentclass[11pt]{report}
        \usepackage[
          height=8in,      % height of the text block
          width=6.2in,       % width of the text block
          top=78pt,        % distance of the text block from the top of the page
          headheight=60pt, % height for the header block
          headsep=12pt,    % distance from the header block to the text block
          heightrounded,   % ensure an integer number of lines
         % showframe,       % show the main blocks
          showcrop=true,
          verbose,         % show the values of the parameters in the log file
        ]{geometry}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{url}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{datetime}
        \usepackage{tgschola}%------------font YES
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \usepackage{enumitem}
        \usepackage{calc}
        \setlength{\headheight}{82pt}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhf{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
        \fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}{lll@{\hspace{1cm}}l@{\hspace{1.6cm}}l}%
                            & &                                 & \multirow{1}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-a} } &  Governement of India \\
                    Web     &:& \url=www.dgqadefence.gov.in=                    & & Ministry of Defence(DGQA)\\
                    E-mail  &:& \url=cqaavl-dgqa@nic.in=                        & & Controllerate of Quality Assurance\\
                    Phone   &:& 044-26841773                                    & & (Armoured Vehicle Electronics)\\
                    Fax     &:& 044-26841881                                    & &  HVF Campus, Avadi\\
                            & &                                                 & & Chennai -- 600 054
                    \end{tabular}}
        \fancyfoot[L]{%
                    \footnotesize 
                         Typeset in \textrm{\LaTeX}}
        %------shortcut for adgqal address
        \newcommand{\adgqaladd}{To,\\
        The ADGQA(L)\\
        HQ DQA(L)/ DGQA(L-2)\\
        "G" Block, P.O. Nirman Bhavan\\
        New Delhi -- 110 011\\} 
        %------shortcut for adgqal address
        \newcommand{\peteradd}{To,\\
        Shri Peter J, PScO\\
        Dy Controller\\
        CQA(AVL)\\
        Avadi, Chennai -- 600 054\\} 
        %-----------------EME trg
        \newcommand{\emetrgadd}{To,\\
        Dte Gen of EME (Trg)\\MGO’s Branch, `B' Block\\IHQ Of MOD(Army)\\DHQ PO, New Delhi --110 105\\
        }
        %---------shortcut for signature block
        \newcommand{\signature}{\begin{tabbing}\\
        xxxxxxxxxxx\=:\=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \kill\\
        \>\>\> (JS Bibra)\\
        \>\>\> Colonel \\
            \end{tabbing}}
        %----------shortcut for subject heading--replace 1 with the \subject{xxxx}
        \newcommand{\subject}[1]{\centerline{\underline{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}
        %------------------------------------------------------------------------
        %----------shortcut for file number
        \newcommand{\filenumber}[2]{xxxxxxxxxxxx\=:\=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \kill\\
        File No: #1\>\>\> #2 \datemy\today\\
        }


        %-----------shortcut for copy to-------
        \newcommand{\copyto}{\underline{\textbf{Copy to:}}\\*[2pt]}
        %---------------------------------------------------------
        \newsavebox{\mybox}
        \newlength{\restofline}
        %----------------------------
        \newcommand{\cc}{%
        \copyto
        \savebox\mybox{\hbox{\underline {PA to Controller, CQA(AVL)} --\hskip 1pt}}
        \noindent\usebox{\mybox}
        \setlength{\restofline}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\mybox-10pt\relax}
        \begin{minipage} [t]{\restofline}
            for information of Controller please.
        \end{minipage}\\[1em]}
        %---------------------------------datetime-----------
        \newdateformat{datemy}{%
            \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
        %---------------------------------------------------------
        \begin{document}
        \begin{tabbing}
            \filenumber{20211/JC/SA}{06}\\                                  
            \peteradd\\                                 
            \subject{ISO:9001:2015}
        \end{tabbing}
                \begin{enumerate}[wide, labelwidth=2em, labelindent=0pt]
        \item The following tasks in connection with ISO certification are assigned to Shri Peter~J, Dy Controller/ QM Coordinator.\\
                \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=\leftmargin+2em]
        \item Printing and Binding of Quality Manual(QM), through a DTP to be identified by the QM Coord--- one copy in color will be prepared\\
        \item After printing and binding of Quality Manual signature of MR and Controller be obtained on pages of the manual where designated\\
        \item After approval of the printed copy of QM, obtain required number of additional copies of QM for distribution as per Distribution List enclosed in the QM \\
        \item Plan for audit schedule be finalised in consultation with MR and Controller\\
        \item Internal Audit be organised as per approved schedule\\
        \item Non conformities be rectified and verified by concerned sections\\
        \item BIS to be approached for Certification Audit and obtain quotation-- no accommodation/food will be provided by the estt, the quotation should be self-contained\\
        \item Organise  audit by BIS rep for successful certification\\ 
                        \end{enumerate}
                        \newpage
        \item A copy of the QM is handed over on CD for the printing and binding work. Please get the tasks completed on priority for successful certification.\\
                \end{enumerate}
    \signature
    \cc
    \newpage


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Not a complete answer, so I'll leave a comment. The vertical spacing is affected by \\ in the `enumerate` environment, please remove them. You can also change the vertical spacing using `\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=\leftmargin+2em,itemsep=2pt,parsep=2pt]` at the beginning of the (a) to (h) enumerate environment, change the value of 2pt as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. I changed some of the keys in the `enumerate` environments, removed all `\\` after items, which is bad practice, and replaced them with an `itemsep=..` key.

I also redefined the `\filenumber` command , basing it on a simple `\makebox[\linewidth]{...}`, with both aruments separated by `\hfill`.

Finally, I redesigned the header so that it fits the text width. I don't think the colons should be aligned, so I deleted one column.

```
   \documentclass[11pt]{report}
        \usepackage[
          height=8in, % height of the text block
          width=6.2in, % width of the text block
          top=78pt, % distance of the text block from the top of the page
          headheight=60pt, % height for the header block
          headsep=12pt, % distance from the header block to the text block
          heightrounded, % ensure an integer number of lines
         % showframe, % show the main blocks
          showcrop=true,
          verbose, % show the values of the parameters in the log file
        ]{geometry}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{url}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{datetime}
        \usepackage{tgschola}%------------font YES
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \usepackage{enumitem}
        \usepackage{calc} 
        \setlength{\headheight}{82pt}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhf{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
        \fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\enspace}lll@{}}%
                              & & \multirow{6}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=.24]{example-image-a} } & Government of India \\
                    Web: & \url=www.dgqadefence.gov.in= & & Ministry of Defence (DGQA)\\
                    E-mail: & \url=cqaavl-dgqa@nic.in= & & Controllerate of Quality Assurance\\
                    Phone: & 044-26841773 & & (Armoured Vehicle Electronics)\\
                    Fax: & 044-26841881 & & HVF Campus, Avadi\\
                             & & & Chennai -- 600 054
                    \end{tabular}}
        \fancyfoot[L]{%
                    \footnotesize
                         Typeset in \textrm{\LaTeX}}
        %------shortcut for adgqal address
        \newcommand{\adgqaladd}{To,\\
        The ADGQA(L)\\
        HQ DQA(L)/ DGQA(L-2)\\
        "G" Block, P.O. Nirman Bhavan\\
        New Delhi -- 110 011\\}
        %------shortcut for adgqal address
        \newcommand{\peteradd}{To,\\
        Shri Peter J, PScO\\
        Dy Controller\\
        CQA(AVL)\\
        Avadi, Chennai -- 600 054\\}
        %-----------------EME trg
        \newcommand{\emetrgadd}{To,\\
        Dte Gen of EME (Trg)\\MGO’s Branch, `B' Block\\IHQ Of MOD(Army)\\DHQ PO, New Delhi --110 105\\
        }
        %---------shortcut for signature block
        \newcommand{\signature}{\begin{tabbing}\\
        xxxxxxxxxxx\=:\=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \kill\\
        \>\>\> (JS Bibra)\\
        \>\>\> Colonel \\
            \end{tabbing}}
        %----------shortcut for subject heading--replace 1 with the \subject{xxxx}
        \newcommand{\subject}[1]{\centerline{\underline{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}}}
        %------------------------------------------------------------------------
        %----------shortcut for file number
% \newcommand{\filenumber}[2]{xxxxxxxxxxxx\=:\=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \kill\\
% File No: #1\>\>\> #2 \datemy\today\\
% }
        \newcommand{\filenumber}[2]{\par
        \makebox[\linewidth][s]{\mbox{File No: #1}\hfill\mbox{#2 \datemy\today}}\\
        }

    %-----------shortcut for copy to-------
    \newcommand{\copyto}{\underline{\textbf{Copy to:}}\\*[2pt]}
    %---------------------------------------------------------
    \newsavebox{\mybox}
    \newlength{\restofline}
    %----------------------------
    \newcommand{\cc}{%
    \copyto
    \savebox\mybox{\hbox{\underline {PA to Controller, CQA(AVL)} --\hskip 1pt}}
    \noindent\usebox{\mybox}
    \setlength{\restofline}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\mybox-10pt\relax}
    \begin{minipage} [t]{\restofline}
        for information of Controller please.
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]}
    %---------------------------------datetime-----------
    \newdateformat{datemy}{%
        \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
    %---------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabbing}
        \filenumber{20211/JC/SA}{06}\\
        \peteradd\\
        \subject{ISO:9001:2015}
    \end{tabbing}
            \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, labelwidth=2em]
    \item The following tasks in connection with ISO certification are assigned to Shri Peter~J, Dy Controller/ QM Coordinator.
            \begin{enumerate}[wide =\leftmargini, leftmargin=*, itemsep=1ex]
    \item Printing and Binding of Quality Manual(QM), through a DTP to be identified by the QM Coord--- one copy in color will be prepared 
    \item After printing and binding of Quality Manual signature of MR and Controller be obtained on pages of the manual where designated 
    \item After approval of the printed copy of QM, obtain required number of additional copies of QM for distribution as per Distribution List enclosed in the QM 
    \item Plan for audit schedule be finalised in consultation with MR and Controller 
    \item Internal Audit be organised as per approved schedule 
    \item Non conformities be rectified and verified by concerned sections 
    \item BIS to be approached for Certification Audit and obtain quotation-- no accommodation/food will be provided by the estt, the quotation should be self-contained 
    \item Organise audit by BIS rep for successful certification 
                    \end{enumerate}
                    \newpage
    \item A copy of the QM is handed over on CD for the printing and binding work. Please get the tasks completed on priority for successful certification.
            \end{enumerate}
\signature
\cc
\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great does the job